# How to disable event firing outside an event?

Tags: event-handlers

How do I disable event firing in code that is not part of an `ItemReceiver`?

E.g.: I have an FeatureActivated event receiver which update a list (adds column) and updates all items to populate the new column. I want to do this without firing the 'ItemUpdated'-event for all items in the list.

Comment: What I don't understand is : Events firing may be disabled for which SharePoint objects/area/domain/scope : web ? Farm ? list ? Item ? Where is the association made ?
Many thanks

Comment: @user16325 See this Question: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/20261/what-is-the-scope-of-disableeventfiring

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use this approach - create class:

```
public class DisabledItemEventsScope : SPItemEventReceiver, IDisposable
{
    private readonly bool oldValue;

    public DisabledItemEventsScope()
    {
        oldValue = EventFiringEnabled;
        EventFiringEnabled = false;
    }

    #region IDisposable Members

    public void Dispose()
    {
        EventFiringEnabled = oldValue;
    }

    #endregion
}
```

using:

```
using (var scope = new DisabledItemEventsScope())
{
   Item.Update();
}
```

from [here](http://adrianhenke.wordpress.com/2010/01/29/disable-item-events-firing-during-item-update/)

Comment: Nice and clean!

Comment: Should this work for updating any item properties without firing an event, or just in that specific situation?

Comment: This will work for any item update

Comment: What if I need to disable event firing on a list, i.e. when I don't have the context of the list in question. I have some SharePoint web part code that needs to update a property of an item in a list. And I want to disable event firing when updating the property of that item, since the list has a registered event receiver.