# Add a document to a library without triggering webhook using Csom

Tags: sharepoint-online, csom

We have a library in SharePointOnline with a webhook. Normally we want the webhook to fire when a document is altered, but sometimes it is required not the fire the webhook. In Sharepoint Onprem we could create a DisabledItemEventsScope  ([How to disable event firing outside an event?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/31655/how-to-disable-event-firing-outside-an-event/31657)). Is it possible to add a document to a library without triggering the webhook using csom?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cuurently there is no CSOM code to disable event firing for webhooks in SharePoint online.

You could create a new user voice as shown below:

https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/forums/329220-sharepoint-dev-platform/suggestions/15147072-provide-flag-to-enable-disable-event-firing-from-r