# Event Handling ItemAdded and ItemUpdated

Tags: document-library

Is it possible to prevent Sharepoint framework to call ItemUpdated event method, after ItemAdded? I want ItemUpdated to be called only when the item is edited. I don't want to let sharepoint call ItemUpdated after ItemAdded.

and/or

Is it possible to pass a parameter from ItamAdded to ItemUpdated event method?

Comment: it looks like you have been trying to use incorrect approach. Could you describe your issue?

Comment: First I want to say that I am using a static variable to get a value in item updating method and I use it in item updated method (i'm doing the same for delete). I don't know if this will work for your case, but you can try it. I am waiting for your feedback.

Answer (score 2):

For your first question, the answer is yes. If you are using SharePoint 2010, then you can use following code in the ItemAdded event to prevent ItemUpdated event being called:

```
    EventFiringEnabled = false;       
    //your code implementation       
    EventFiringEnabled = true;
```

If you are using MOSS 2007, you can use following code

```
   DisableEventFiring();
   //your code implementation
   EnableEventFiring();
```

For the second question, I don't think it is possible.

Comment: For the second question you can use additional field in list item which should be hidden. But in my opinion, the behevior when the item updated event is invoked after item adding event is incorrect. I think that user10606 did something wrong.

Comment: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/45470/627 Basically the same

Comment: @Alexander and how do you plan to persist a new value to that field? ;) calling Update()? and I dont think disabling event firing will keep itemUpdated from firing when adding a file. The reason ItemUpdate is called is that the provisioning of the file is a two step process: first the file is added, then the metadata (as i remember it). When adding publishing pages, ItemUpdated is called several times. Disabling event firing is ment to short circuit getting recursive loops when calling Update() in an ItemUpdated event receiver.

Comment: @AndersRask, the question does not contains information about type of item, thus I thought that this question is about typical list item, not a document. Also you are right, I mixed up ItemAdding and ItemAdded method. In the fist method you can use AfterProperties to set up value in the hidden field.

Comment: Have you tried this? Im pretty sure you cant set them (they are only get properties) other than by setting a value in the field itself. It might work, but before/after properties work differently on different types of items, and often not the way you would expect...

Comment: Can I use Properties bag? I set a key and value in ItemAdded, and when in ItemUpdated it forgets it.

Comment: ItemUpdated does NOT get called when a file is uploaded to a default document library (i.e. the dialog to edit fields doesn't get shown), or if the user cancels the dialog - this leads me to believe SP does something like uploads the document with the file name, and then updates its records if any custom field values get set (at least for SP2010, haven't tested in 2007/2013)

Answer (score 0):

Check following link, in this link there is solution for "Share value between itemupdating and itemupdated events in SandBox Event receiver "

http://sharepointweblog.blogspot.in/2014/05/sharepoint-2010-share-value-between.html

Comment: Please do not post link only answers, instead add the details from the link to your post and use the link as merely a source